# SQL Triggers, how to copy a value from one column to another while updating the first one

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

let's say this is our table of PRICES

```
 curP |  oldP | ID 
+------------------+
|210  | null  |  1 |
+------------------+
```

I would like to create a trigger when I do:

```
UPDATE PRICES
SET curP = 300
WHERE ID = 1;
```

It would show our table like this:

```
 curP |  oldP | ID 
+------------------+
|300  | 210   |  1 |
+------------------+
```

How would a trigger for this look like? I only want to copy the old value into the new column. Please help (I am working in Oracle)
*edit: Whenever I tried to make a trigger it would give an error that tables are mutating ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `BEFORE UPDATE` row-level `TRIGGER`.  Here's an example:

First create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE PRICES(CURP NUMBER, OLDP NUMBER, ID NUMBER);
```

Then create the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CURP_TO_OLDP
BEFORE UPDATE ON PRICES
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    :NEW.OLDP := :OLD.CURP;
  END;
  /
```

Then test it.  First add some initial data:

```
INSERT INTO PRICES VALUES (100,NULL,1);
INSERT INTO PRICES VALUES (200,NULL,2);

SELECT * FROM PRICES ORDER BY 3;

CURP  OLDP  ID  
100         1   
200         2
```

Then update:

```
UPDATE PRICES SET CURP = 1000;

SELECT * FROM PRICES ORDER BY 3;

CURP  OLDP  ID  
1000  100   1   
1000  200   2
```

Comment: would this work if I only want to update for example the row that has the ID 1 and not the one with the ID 2?

Comment: @kiki . . . This answers your question.  You can add an `if` statement specific to an `id`, but if you have another question, you should accept this answer and ask *another* question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked actually for only one ID without any if statements. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have one point in code from where you do update , you  can do it in update statement without trigger

`update prices 
      set oldp  = curp, curp = newvalue
  where id = yourid`